# Does a transaction cover the subroutines?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

When I `begin transaction` and `exec` a stored procedure, does that transaction cover the changes made by the stored procedure I executed? Would a `rollback transaction` cancel the changes made by the stored procedure which is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does cover.
All of the actions performed to database within the scope of the same transaction will be rolled back.